# How to convert a given Vikram Samvat date into corresponding Gregorian Date?

Tags: vedas, time, calendar, astronomy

I want to convert particularly, Shravan Shuklapaksha Dwitiya of Vikram Samvat 667 into its corresponding Gregorian date. 
link: [Vikram Samvat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vikram_Samvat)

Comment: You can use Panchanga.